# Display data in consistent format for array of documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a  collection personemail with array of documents

```
{ "Name" : "A", "Email" : [ { "EmailAddress" : "a@home.com", "EmailType" : "Home" }, { "EmailAddress" : "a@work.com", "EmailType" : "Work" } ] }
{ "Name" : "B", "Email" : [ { "EmailAddress" : "b@work.com", "EmailType" : "Work" } ] }
{ "Name" : "C" }
```

I have to display data in below format, ie if we a person is not having home / work address , it should be displayed as "No data" if home or work email is not available preferably in same order (Home email first , Work email second)

```
{ "Name" : "A", "Email" : [ { "EmailAddress" : "a@home.com", "EmailType" : "Home" }, { "EmailAddress" : "a@work.com", "EmailType" : "Work" } ] }
{ "Name" : "B", "Email" : [ { "EmailAddress" : "No Data", "EmailType" : "Home" }, { "EmailAddress" : "b@work.com", "EmailType" : "Work" } ] }
{ "Name" : "C", "Email" : [ { "EmailAddress" : "No Data", "EmailType" : "Home" }, { "EmailAddress" : "No Data", "EmailType" : "Work" } ] }
```

I thought of implementing this with $unwind or $switch function . Suggestions please

Comment: Don't you think, you are trying SQL typo results from NO-SQL. ?

Comment: Yes.. i have to compare this data with csv input source..I am new to mongo db and was just checking if there is a way in mongo.

Comment: You are saving "No Data", it reflects no information is saved just not to save NULL you are saving this. So, i believe when you are comparing and data field is miss here, it reflects you had no data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "Name": 1,
    "Email": {
      "$map": {
        "input": ["Home", "Work"],
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "$ifNull": [
            { "$arrayElemAt": [
              { "$filter": {
                "input": "$Email",
                "as": "e",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$e.EmailType", "$$m" ] }
              }},
              0
            ]},
            { "EmailAddress": "No Data", "EmailType": "$$m" }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which produces:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591e7d66cb1a9433dab779cc"),
        "Name" : "A",
        "Email" : [
                {
                        "EmailAddress" : "a@home.com",
                        "EmailType" : "Home"
                },
                {
                        "EmailAddress" : "a@work.com",
                        "EmailType" : "Work"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591e7d66cb1a9433dab779cd"),
        "Name" : "B",
        "Email" : [
                {
                        "EmailAddress" : "No Data",
                        "EmailType" : "Home"
                },
                {
                        "EmailAddress" : "b@work.com",
                        "EmailType" : "Work"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("591e7d66cb1a9433dab779ce"),
        "Name" : "C",
        "Email" : [
                {
                        "EmailAddress" : "No Data",
                        "EmailType" : "Home"
                },
                {
                        "EmailAddress" : "No Data",
                        "EmailType" : "Work"
                }
        ]
}
```

But personally I'd do that transformation in client code, since it's less obtuse. As a quick shell example:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc.Email = ["Home", "Work"].map( m => {
    if (!doc.hasOwnProperty('Email'))
      doc.Email = [];
    var val = doc.Email.filter(e => e.EmailType === m)[0];

    return (val == null) ? { "EmailAddress": "No Data", "EmailType": m }
      : val; 
  });
  printjson(doc);
})
```

Basically though you use your "uniform" array of "Home" and "Work" as a source to `$map`, then lookup the elements in the documents current `Email` array. anything that returned a `null` on the lookup is swapped with the default data.

Comment: Thank you neil. Your solution gave me lot of inputs about querying in mongo